# Why is there unsigned type in DEX executables when there's no unsigned type in Java?

Tags: android, types, dalvik, unsigned

The unsigned types in DEX format are:

```
ubyte       8-bit unsigned int
ushort      16-bit unsigned int, little-endian
uint        32-bit unsigned int, little-endian
ulong       64-bit unsigned int, little-endian
uleb128     unsigned LEB128, variable-length (see below)
uleb128p1   unsigned LEB128 plus 1, variable-length (see below)
```

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html

However unsigned types are only introduced since Java 8 and Android's dx as well as Jack and Jill compiler still doesn't support Java 8. So why are those types introduced? Is there any chance for Java code to emit instructions that use those types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those types are for the DEX file format itself.  The meta-data in the header, which holds things like method counts and file offsets, is not tied to any particular language.

Besides, DEX could be used for non-Java languages.

Comment: Java bytecodes can also be used for non-Java languages. And Java class files may also need to store method counts and file offsets like that, but they don't need unsigned types

Comment: Have you read the Java bytecode reference? It uses many unsigned values. For example, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.aload uses an unsigned byte index, or an unsigned two-byte index for the "wide" version.